# how to export a range from excel to a specific ms access 2010 field

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, vba

I am able to export a range to an entire ms access 2010 table and when you run the query multiple the range will append to the existing dataset (can you change this default append behaviour)?

However is it possible to export a single column range in excel to a specific field within an ms office table?

For example if table test has three column fields (f1,f2,f3) and I want to export the data to field f2 can I do that?

Comment: You can export to a (new) temp table, then run a query moving the data from this to the fields you wish in another table.

Answer (score 0):

You can import Excel data into Access, from Access.

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm

As you know, you can export Excel data to Access.

Option Explicit

```
Sub AccImport()
    Dim acc As New Access.Application
    acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb"
    acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
            TableName:="tblExcelImport", _
            Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            Range:="Folio_Data_original$A1:B10"
    acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
    acc.Quit
    Set acc = Nothing
End Sub
```

If the data needs massaging, you can set it up in Excel, on a new sheet, and when it's in the structure you want, just send it to Access.  Or, export a chunk to a generic Access table, and run an Append Query, to move that data from your 'staging' table to your final 'production' table.